# issue with SQL command

Tags: c#, sql

I'm getting an exception when trying to run my code, I'm fairly new to SQL not sure if I've used the right syntax.

`"Column 'news.score' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`

````
foreach(PatientModel a in patientList)
    {
         try
         {
             con.Open();
             cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(datetime), score FROM news WHERE(patientID = @patientID)";
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientID", a.PatientID);
             reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

             while (reader.Read())
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("");
                 a.Score = (int)reader["score"];
             }
         }
         catch
         {
             con.Close();
         }
    }
con.Close();```
````

Comment: Try adding `GROUP BY score`  into the sql command. `cmd.CommandText = 
   @"SELECT MAX(datetime), 
            score 
       FROM news 
      WHERE (patientID = @patientID)
   GROUP BY score";`

Comment: You have to ask yourself what that means, though. Does it make sense to get the maximum `datetime` for all rows that have each `score` value? That's what adding `GROUP BY score` will do. Is that what you want? If not, what were you expecting to get?

Comment: This approach to database access is *very old.*  Consider a more modern approach like Dapper, or even Entity Framework Core.  There are many benefits, not the least of which is much simpler code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT MAX(datetime), score FROM news WHERE patientID = @patientID GROUP BY score
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp